# GTK applications do not start

Tags: 10.04, server, gtk, xorg

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 Server on nodes of a computational cluster, and I access the nodes via ssh. I configured a X server, which I start with the command `startx -- -ac`. The server is running fine on port :0. Then, I set the environment variable DISPLAY to :0. Now, when I run a GTK application on the node, it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Now, my question is, is there any runtime library that I need for running GTK applications on top of a X server? I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I can't tell what :P

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by myself after searching for a while. There is apparently no need for a further package on top of the a proper X server, but you need to allow local connections to your X server by using the following commands:

```
DISPLAY=:0    
xhost +LOCAL:
```

Then it works!